# GRUB Error: unknown filesystem сразу после установки Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

Сразу после установки Ubuntu на диск с виндой после перезагрузки не работает GRUB выдавая ошибку `unknown filesystem`. Попытался выяснить какой раздел пренадлежит Ubuntu: `grub rescue>ls (hd*,msdos*)/` возвращает unknown filesystem для всех разделов кроме NTFS-ных. Если зайти из-под live cd то раздел с Ubuntu существует и содержит файлы, характерные для linux-а. Пробовал разные версии Ubuntu, флешки и способы записи - не помогает. Пытаюсь установить на Hp elitebook 8470p.

Comment: grub2 же? похоже, что драйверов нет для типов разделов

Comment: если в BIOS UEFI - то только grub2

Comment: оказалось что проблема была с внешним жестким диском